# How to return List with Streams in this case?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have this method

```
private List<StudentVO> getStudentVOList() {
    List<HouseDTO> hDtoList = new ArrayList<HouseDTO>();
    for (HouseDTO hdn : hDtoList) {
        if (hdn.getHouseName().equals("ZSRT")) {
            return hdn.getStudents();
        }
    }
```

which i am trying to convert to Java 8 , i have tried as shown below

```
return  hDtoList.stream().filter(hdn->hdn.getHouseName().equals("ZSRT")).map(hdn->hdn.getStudents()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

-

```
public class HouseDTO {

    public String getHouseName() {
        return houseName;
    }
    public void setHouseName(String houseName) {
        this.houseName = houseName;
    }
    public List<StudentVO> getStudents() {
        return students;
    }
    public void setStudents(List<StudentVO> students) {
        this.students = students;
    }
    private String houseName ;
    List<StudentVO> students;
}


public class StudentVO {

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getRollNo() {
        return rollNo;
    }
    public void setRollNo(int rollNo) {
        this.rollNo = rollNo;
    }
    private String name;
    private int rollNo;
}
```

Comment: It is ok that you shrink the code to avoid clutter, but replacing it with stuff that doesn't make sense doesn't help. So don't make it look like you instantiate a new Arraylist for `hDtoList` and then directly run a enhanced for loop over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `findAny` or `findFirst` after the `map` then `orElse(someDefaulValues)`, in your case an empty collection.

```
return  hDtoList.stream()
                .filter(hdn->hdn.getHouseName().equals("ZSRT"))
                .findFirst()
                .map(StudentVO::getStudents)
                .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
```

Comment: Better use `Collections.emptyList()`.

Comment: Thank you @Nikolas sorry bad syntax because i'm using phone I fix it

Comment: Thank you very much @Nikolas, I appriciate it

Comment: You could have kept your original `.map(StudentVO::getStudents) .findFirst()`, as there’s no semantic difference, due to the lazy nature of the Stream, it still would would only call `getStudents` at most once, on the matching `StudentVO` element, if there is one.

Comment: Hi @Holger ah you are correct, yes I change it because I thought in another scenrio, which is if I use map before findFind it will return just one Student and this is not correct, so using map first of findFind will return the first list of student of that collection, so you propose to rollback my solution or stick on this one. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

try the following with the use of `flatMap`

```
List<StudentVO> studentVOList = hDtoList.stream()
            .filter(h -> h.getHouseName().equals("ZSRT"))
            .flatMap(h -> h.getStudentVOList().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<StudentVO> studentsList=hDtoList.stream().filter(hdto->hdto.getHouseName().equals("ZSRT")).findFirst().get().getStudents();

// studentsList may be null if not found
```